# Absolve v. acquit

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Can one be judicially "absolved" only after being found guilty first (for example, by way of pardon)? In other words, can "absolve" be used instead of "acquit"?

> **absolve** Set or declare (someone) free from blame, guilt, or responsibility.

> **acquit** Free (someone) from a criminal charge by a verdict of not guilty.

*([as](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/absolve) [per](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/acquit) Lexico)*

Comment: Please edit to show that you've looked up "absolve" in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions remain. If you're asking about a strictly legal use, you might need to ask on a stack exchange about law.

Comment: @AndyBonner of course, I have

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev What about these definitions is confusing to you? The definition of "absolve" doesn't mention criminal justice. A quick search for the word should demonstrate this.

Comment: @gotube Lexico included this example: ‘The pardon absolved them of any crimes’

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev That's the normal definition of "absolve". A pardon is not the same thing as a "verdict of not guilty".

Comment: @gotube I mean it seemed to me as if it could generally mean "relieve someone of legal guilt for something", not necessarily a not guilty verdict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Acquit" has a specific legal meaning. It means that a court found the person to be not guilty. It is a factual description of what happened in the court. Nobody informed as to the facts would have a different opinion as to whether a person was acquitted or not.

"Absolve" has a broader meaning and it is subjective. To absolve someone means that you forgive them.

Just because someone was acquitted by a court doesn't mean they are absolved. If someone is acquitted, for instance, on a legal technicality that wouldn't mean they were absolved of blame from a moral perspective. Lots of people might have different opinions as to whether they are absolved, but nobody should have a different opinion as to whether they were acquitted.

Equally, even if someone is convicted that doesn't mean they can't be absolved / forgiven.

Comment: But "absolve" has a legal dimension too, doesn't it?